# Updating or inserting new row in child entity

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, one parent and multiple children entities. The child table has the foreign key of the parent. My problem comes with updating or inserting a new row.

I receive a list of beans with information from the frontend and based on a value in each bean I need to either update a row if a child with that value exists in the child table (which has multiple columns needed to be updated) or insert a new row if one doesn't exist.

Besides getting the list of children from the parent entity and doing a double-for loop style matching, is there a better approach? Here I'll be matching the each child entity value with each other bean from the list and if there's a match it's an update otherwise an insert.

Hibernate in this case does the right thing in the sense that it keep adding rows because there is no id. Thanks!

Comment: Too vague. Post your code instead of describing it. Also define what you mean by "better". It can be many things: more concise, more efficient, doing fewer requests, etc.

Comment: use a set, not a list, and implement equals and hash?

Comment: require some code to help understand what you are trying to achieve. Hibernate can be configured in many ways and there are many ways to save a Parent-Child into database.
You could either go for saveorupdate(object) or save(object) or set up Cascade during hibernate one to many mapping

Answer (score 0):

You could extract a sublist containing all beans relative to children entities and then fetch and update them. 
Then extract a sublist for all beans relative to children that needs to be created and insert new entities.
This could be a more functional approach, more feasible (and easy) if your env is java 8.